# Implement Variadic function in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am trying to write wrapper for a log function with a printf-like behavior.

Can anyone tell me why the following example does not work?

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void message(int level, const char* format, ...)
{
    if(level > 3)
        return;

    static char msgBuff[1024] = {0};

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    snprintf(msgBuff, sizeof(msgBuff), format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    printf("%s", msgBuff); // Dummy Call
}


int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    message(3, "This is a test: %s %i", "The answer is ", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test:  0
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf

Comment: It's better to avoid such functions. `printf`/`scanf` are perhaps the most harmful functions ever designed not only in the history of C but in the history of programming, due to their non-existent type safety and format complexity.

Comment: You didn't include `<stdio.h>` according to the code shown.  That seems odd, and definitely a bad idea.  You didn't include a newline at the end of the message.  That might delay the appearance of the output.

Comment: With vsnprintf it works.

Comment: Yeah — you must use the `v*printf()` functions to process `va_list` arguments.  Your choice on whether to delete the question — it is pretty much in the typo category, but the compiler cannot easily spot the mistake (and GCC does not manage to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to `snprintf` after the format string must be the individual arguments expected according to the conversion specifiers in the format string. `argptr` is not such an argument, so the call is incorrect.

To print variable arguments using a `va_list`, call `vsnprintf` instead of `snprintf`.